# Microsoft Excel - Combining Tables into one "Consolidated" Table

Tags: excel

I have 6 sheets in a workbook. Each sheet has an identical table for sections within my organization to track their personnel.

I'd like to have a consolidated sheet that serves as a master sheet that can be refreshed as the section leaders update their rosters. Is that possible?

I've looked into creating relationships, but Pivot Tables don't merge the tables, they just display them all. I'd like one table that refreshes - linked to the section's tables so that when a row is added or deleted, then once refreshed the consolidated sheet/table shows the update. For example:

```
Sheet 1:
Last Name Column: 
Hall

Sheet 2:
Last Name Column: 
Smith

Sheet 3:
Last Name Column: 
Jacobs
```

Combined Sheet:

```
Last Name Column:
Hall
Smith
Jacobs
```

I need to replicate the entire table though, not just one column. Your help is much appreciated, thank you!

-Dustin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Get and Transform" aka Power Query to solve the the problem. It's made for combining data :). Search for "EXCEL merge tables Power Query"

Comment: Thanks!! Works like a charm! Here is where I found the answer using your search term: https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+merge+tables+power+query&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS869US869&oq=EXCEL+merge+tables+Power+Query&aqs=chrome.0.0l8.315j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_baHTXvOiJIjBytMP7bCMsA030